# Configuration error lapis. Luarocks may not be configured correctly

Tags: lua, luarocks

Having some trouble installing Lapis. I am working in Ubuntu and keep getting this error every time I use the luarocks install method to fetch lapis.... Any advice ?

What can I change in my settings to correct this error : "lpcap.c:6:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory"

```
    Missing dependencies for lapis:
lpeg 
luasocket 
lua-cjson 

Using https://rocks.moonscript.org/lpeg-0.12-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
gcc -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -c lpcap.c -o lpcap.o
lpcap.c:6:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lua.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://rocks.moonscript.org/lpeg-0.12-1.src.rock - Build error: Failed compiling object lpcap.o
bitsguru@ubuntu:~/Desktop/me/lapis-master$
```

Maybe this is a better report:

```
    os.execute:     cd '/tmp/luarocks_lpeg-0.12-1-8126/lpeg-0.12' && gcc -O2 -fPIC '-I/usr/include' '-c' 'lpcap.c' '-o' 'lpcap.o'
lpcap.c:6:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lua.h"
```

Comment: Causes because of missing lua-dev / liblua5.1-0-dev (for ubuntu) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LuaRocks doesn't find the Lua include files. The location of these files is configured in `site_config.lua` as `site_config.LUA_INCDIR`, and it should be `/usr/include/lua5.1` or `/usr/include/lua5.2` on Ubuntu depending on the Lua version you want to use. Fix that value accordingly, or if you don't have `site_config.lua` (it should be in the same directory as the other LuaRocks modules), you can create it by running `./configure` on the LuaRocks source code.